# Panda instead of activity

Tags: bug, status-completed, activity-summary

I'm getting a panda when I look for [my activity](https://stackexchange.com/users/935589/gerrit?tab=activity):

> We apologize for any inconvenience, but an unexpected error occurred while you were browsing our site.
> It's not you, it's us. This is our fault.

Although I think the panda is rather endearing, I would like to see my activity.

[image: Fail-panda]

Comment: That means they are aware of the error, try again in a few minutes.

Comment: When you get an error message indicating a temporary server problem the appropriate thing to do is want, not badger people for it not working.  If it's been down for a really long time, then consider looking for an announcement of some sort explaining the downtime.

Comment: Then why does it say *It's not strictly necessary, but if you'd like to give us additional information about this error, do so at our feedback site, http://meta.stackoverflow.com.*?

Comment: Why did you push the panda off the slide!? Poor panda...

Comment: Probably because that's shorter than "It's not strictly necessary, but if you'd like to give us additional information about this error, and you've ruled out issues on your end, and this has been going on for more than ten or fifteen minutes, do so at our feedback site, meta.stackoverflow.com (assuming nobody else has already posted a similar bug report)."

Comment: @gerrit And what additional information have you provided, other than to say that you're getting an error?  You also posted a question, you asked the team when the site would be back up, as opposed to "I got this error when doing such and such and I'm reporting it as requested here".

Answer (score 11, accepted):

We broke a critical barrier with Lucene.Net internally with respect to file locking earlier.  While we've deployed some optimizations now and will need to make a larger shift long-term, our reduced web farm out in Oregon is feeling a bit of pain.

We're hitting limits that don't have an easy solution as certain elements on Lucene were not ported that would be very useful at the moment (`MMapDirectory` and `NIOFSDirectory`).  Since those aren't quick to slap in and test, we're in a bit of a bind deciding what to do...the community and support for Lucene.Net may not be at a level we're comfortable with continuing on.  That's partly because we may be the largest volume user of it (I'd *love* to talk to anyone with an equivalent volume level, if you know anyone send them my way).

Currently, you'll notice search results are only 1000, not 5000, search quotas for backend processes have been reduced, some additional tuning on the code side has also been done.

For now we're back under 30% CPU on 5 web servers and that still makes us a bit uneasy.  Some more hardware is on the way and we're making performance improvements across the board, we'll try our best to ensure the sites remain online until the move back to New York approximately a month from now.

Comment: Maybe we could fund Lucene.NET improvements for longer term?

Comment: I'm not sure we have enough left over after we blew most of the money on hookers and booze.  Kidding aside, we're looking at all options, also including non-.Net stacks for a service model.