# Accessing the Community Bot's activity page makes the panda fall over

Tags: bug, community-user, activity

This is the activity page:

[Community Activity](https://stackexchange.com/users/-1/community?tab=activity)

[image: generic error page for the Community Bot's activity page, showing an error message and a panda falling over]

Last time something was up with the [web farm](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/158373/175002) (I presume full of spiders?)

My activity page is fine. What's going on with that bot?

Comment: The database isn't capable of loading that much information before timing out, which is why [the "all" tab was removed on its per-site profiles](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/371896/community-user-missing-the-all-subtab-under-all-actions). We will likely remove that tab on the network hub too.

Comment: [Meta SE's Community's Activity](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/-1/community?tab=activity) gives me the "Oops!" page, but sans panda

Comment: @animuson that must be a lot of info... I'd imagine some caching would help greatly.